# Debugging console to Visual Studio 2008 from Windows CE device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, remote-debugging

I'm developing code for a SH4-based Windows CE 5.0 device, using Visual Studio 2008.

The remote debugger is nice - I can see variables, set breakpoints and single step. But what I don't seem to find is a debugging "console" that would pass strings from my code onto the debugger itself.

Maybe it's just that using jQuery (and other Web techniques) has made this kind of debugging to be taken for granted, but really - it's not there. Am I missing something obvious?

What I do find is a [OSCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms905190.aspx) method of storing a debugging log (with roll-over) on the device itself. Is that all there is?

ADDENDUM:

The CeLog, CeLogFlush, OSCapture tools seem half-way what I want (logging on the target device itself). But there's no download. Are these parts of Platform builder os something and I'm out of luck since the device does not already have them?

ADDENDUM II:

Simply using 'fprintf()' to output strings seems to put them on the application's main window. That's enough for me to get started. To rephrase, what I'm looking for is 'fprintf_to_host()'.

Comment: The remote debugger lets you inspect string variables too.

Comment: Sure... So are you suggesting concatenating a log into a variable, and watching that.. That would work. But I remain puzzled that there is no "console" output as such. It's often good to see the course of events that happened (not just the final state).

Comment: There's no hosting process that redirects Control.Write() calls to the Output window.  Try Debug.PrintLine() instead.  OutputDebugString if you code in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little unsure of what you want.  I *think* what you want is the ability to have debug info output from your app and have it shown in Studio, yes?  If that't the case, use the `DEBUGMSG` macro, something like this:

```
DEBUGMSG(TRUE, (_T("My Variable: %i\r\n"), varname));
```

Where the first param is a condition under which to actually print (so this case would always print) and the second works like a printf for formatting variables.  Note that it's in unicode.

Comment: THis is EXACTLY what I wanted - thanks. Cannot believe I managed not to find any of these: OutputDebugString, DEBUGMSG, DEBUGCHK, ASSERT, ASSERTMSG. Thanks a lot!